# How to utilize the sparsity of tensor?

Tags: sparse-matrix, tensor

For dense matrix contain lots of zeros, `scipy.sparse` implement sparse matrix to store and manipulate it efficiently.

But if a tensor (higher than 2-D) is sparse, we can also utilize the sparsity, are there packages realized the store and contraction operation efficently? Or are there papers study on it?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There's at least one package in `pypi` that seeks to expand the `scipy.sparse` to work with more dimensions.  `scipy.sparse` itself is trying to switch to `arrays`, that will be more compatible with `numpy.ndarray`, though the change so far is just in name.  `scipy.sparse` is still 2d, modelled (somewhat) on the `np.matrix` subclass.

Sparse math was most developed for linear systems, such as Finite Element and Finite Difference modeling.  So math like matrix multiplication and various linear equation solvers go the most attention.

In `scipy.sparse`, the COO format is preferred for matrix creation.  In theory expanding it to handle more dimensions is easy, just add more index arrays.  The DOK format should also be easy to expand, since it's a `dict` with a tuple keys.

But COO does not implement indexing or math.  Even conversion to a dense array for display uses a conversion to CSR.

CSR (and CSC) is where most math is implements, along with indexing.  For this, COO values have to be sorted by row, and duplicate coordinates are summed (that's mainly a convenience for creating FEA style stiffness matrices with overlapping nodes).

The COO row array is then replaced with a `indptr` array which has one value per row (plus 1).  Expanding this CSR (condensed row) format to 3d+ is less obvious.

The math for doing matrix multiplication using the CSR format is well developed.

Element-wise math, such as `sin`, square, etc, just requires applying the corresponding `numpy` operation to the `data` array.  It doesn't change the `sparsity`, the coordinates of those nonzero terms.

Changing the sparsity of a CSR matrix is considered to be expensive, and will raise a warning.

LIL format was developed to make iterative element changes easier.  In scipy data is stored as an object dtype array of lists - one list for each row.  It implements indexing, and may also do some math (?).  Like CSR the expansion to 3d is conceptually harder.

At least with CSR format, indexing is actually implemented with matrix multiplication.  That is, it constructs a `extractor` matrix, to produce the desired result.  Row and column sums are also implemented with matrix multiplication.

So for simple data storage, a COO (or DOK) format can be expanded to more dimensions.  But a lot of other 'manipulation' is closely tied to the 2d matrix CSR format.